# Azure Postgres Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, postgresql-9.1

Can any one help on creating **Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper** in **Azure Postgres SQL** ?

Comment: Why did you tag this with the ancient version 9.1?

Comment: Hi @Raju, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Azure Postgres SQL extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-extensions#dblink-and-postgres_fdw):

- Currently, outbound connections from Azure Database for PostgreSQL
  are not supported, except for connections to other Azure Database for
  PostgreSQL servers in the same region.

And there isn't the Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper `oracle_fdw`. It's not supported.

Others have post these [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597976-azure-database-for-postgresql/suggestions/38912878-oracle-fdw-extension) for Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper, but still with no response. We can continue to vote it up, then product team could see it.
[image]

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a hosted database service, you only get to use those extensions which the hosting providers offers you.  Azure does not offer oracle_fdw, so you cannot use it.